# What is the difference between the slope and the angular coefficient?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is the difference between the slope and the angular coefficient?

Comment: They are synonyms.

Comment: What is the cause of telling angular coefficient?

Comment: See this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Barrow#Calculating_tangents) for a description of how the phrase was coined and used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @YvesDaoust wrote, they are synonyms.

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Barrow#Calculating_tangents) that Isaac Barrow coined the phrase *angular coefficient* "in accordance with a suggestion made by Sluze" (who is called [René-François de Sluse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9-Fran%C3%A7ois_de_Sluse) elsewhere).